# I would like to move yii framework folder outside of www access

Tags: php, frameworks

I am about to start using Yii framework for some small php projects (I am used to using the code igniter framework previously).

I want to know two things:
a) Is it possible to move the /framework folder outside of the web root on linux (centOS in particular) for example: /var/framework_here

b) Could you point me to resources or articles about this and how to actually carry out the task?

I've moved the framework DIR outside of public_html (outside my web root) and tried modifying the paths in the demo projects but they don't function - so I guess *I'm doing it wrong*.

So far i've only been able to find info on sending the 'protected' directory within a yii project outside normal web access.

Perhaps I've mis-understood, but I thought doing what i want to do would greatly improve system security - that is actually the main reason i want to do this so again I'm open to suggestions/comments.

Thanks

Comment: This should be possible. What paths did you modify?

Comment: I modified the paths within the project this line:
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';

I changed to ../../../../

Maybe it needs to be absolute as per Alehandro's answer. I'll try both answers and come back

Answer (score 3):

You should modify index.php in each demo project.
Find line

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
```

And change it to something like

```
$yii='/Absolute path to framework folder/yii.php';
```

Comment: And will Yii still function ok?

Comment: Accepted this one as I am trying to be more secure than even .htaccess can provide

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to move it out. All you need to do is put a `.htaccess` file inside the folder of the framework with the following content:

```
# Access denied folder
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Doing so you disable the access the folder to anyone outside the server.

For more informations you can give a look here: https://www.google.it/search?q=htaccess+tutorial